# "echo %JAVA_HOME%" returns wrong path even though System JAVA_HOME Environment variable set

Tags: java, echo, java-home

As far as I can tell my System `JAVA_HOME` Variables are set correctly, but `echo %JAVA_HOME%` returns a wrong path (it is for an old version of Java) even after I restarted windows.

[image: Here are my environment settings]

Another program also thinks `JAVA_HOME` is set to this wrong path.

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: [Change it to be relevant..?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) It is probably a System Environment Variable.

Comment: I did change it. Didn't I?

Comment: Restarting didn't work. Windows still thinks JAVA_HOME is set to ...\jre1.8.0_121 instead of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1 to which I set it in the Systemvariables

Comment: Is it still in the System Variables after a restart..? If so, that's odd. Something *has* to be setting it somehow.

Comment: Yes it is still set to everything like in the picture.

Comment: I removed non-relevant comments and updated the question for clarity. Good luck :}

Comment: Have you restarted your cmd prompt window since you set the variable? If you haven't restarted your terminal, the changes won't have been loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much user2864740  :) @the_storyteller Yes I restarted Windows

Comment: Dis you delete all références to thé Old path on thé environnent Var?

Comment: @GregArtisi I have no more references to the old path in my Sytemvariables. Do you mean this with "environnent Var"?

Comment: @Rednaxelus Post how the issue was solved *as an Answer* and then accept it (there is no reason to use "SOLVED:" on SO :) This will make it easier for others to find if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I had a different local User Variable set for JAVA_HOME but I didn't see, and couldn't access it because I needed administration rights to view them. When I accessed through administration rights I only saw the variables for the Administrator User.

Answer (score -1):

For when you have a corporate/job laptop which is kinda restricted for other users;
I went into the Registry editor, went into every user in `HKEY_USERS` and checked / changed the paths there accordingly.